# List view postion comes to top after append data

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view that fetch data from server when it scroll to bottom. once the data received it pass to the adapter via an array list.

But when i set the array list values to adapter, it appends the data and automatically the position moves to top.

Could some one tell me what is the problem occured here?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you recreated new Adapter and set it to your listview.
If you do like that, your listview will scroll to top.

To keep your listview item position, just call mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); after update your array list.

Hope it can help you!